# Clock Override alternative?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, 21.10

I've used Clock Override for some time and am very happy with the formatting options it lets me choose. After I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10, I found that that format needed re-applying, and that's when I quickly found that Clock Override has not been updated for newer versions of Gnome ([nor does it seem will any time soon](https://github.com/stuartlangridge/gnome-shell-clock-override/issues/61)).

Can anyone recommend an alternative or a way to do what Clock Override does another way?

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the folks at OMG Ubuntu!, I'm happy to say that there is an alternative to Clock Override.

[Date Menu Formatter](http://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4655/date-menu-formatter/)